# log4j2: Using filename with digits in RollingFile appender

Tags: numbers, log4j2, filenames, digits, rollingfileappender

I have a log4j2 configuration, that just works fine.
But I want even the latest logfile to also have digits in the file name, so that the latest file is always on top.

Instead of this:

```
|-- Project
      |-- logfile.01.log
      |-- logfile.02.log
      |-- logfile.log
```

I want to look it like this:

```
|-- Project
      |-- logfile.01.log
      |-- logfile.02.log
      |-- logfile.03.log
```

Following is my configuration for logging with log4j2

**log4j2.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="pattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        <Property name="filename" value="C:\Project\log\logfile.log"/>
        <Property name="filepattern" value="C:\Project\log\logfile.%02i.log"/>
        <Property name="filesize" value="10 MB"/>
        <Property name="rollovermax" value="40"/>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${filename}" filePattern="${filepattern}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${filesize}"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${rollovermax}" fileIndex="min"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**I tried to modify the filename in the following ways**

`<Property name="filename" value="C:\Project\log\logfile.01.log"/>`
-> *leads to only one logfile that will always be overwritten.*
`<Property name="filename" value="C:\Project\log\logfile.%02i.log"/>`
-> *leads to a logfile with %02i in it's name and then the normal rotation starts.*
`<Property name="filename" value="C:\Project\log\logfile.%i.log"/>`
-> *the same but with %i in it's name.*

I even left the whole filename blank and empty but that only leads to no file at all.
`<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="" filePattern="${filepattern}">`
`<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName= filePattern="${filepattern}">`

Comment: Did you try **without** specifying the `fileName` property?

Comment: Yes I did. But then you get no logfile at all.

Comment: If you specify an **empty** `fileName=""` your configuration will not work at all, but if you **omit** the `fileName` attribute (which is the only way for it to be `null`), a [direct write rollover strategy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#directwrite-rollover-strategy) will be automatically selected and it will start logging to `logfile.1.log`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. At first it wasn't clear to me that I had to change the rollover strategy. But now it works like a charm.  
As always, everything has a downside. The DirectWriteRolloverStrategy does not rename existing files, so the file with the highest number is now the most current.  
But this is closer to what I wanted than before.